# Support landscape orientation for horizontalSizeClass=.Regular in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to build an app that supports portrait AND landscape orientations for iOS devices with regular horizontal size class, and portrait only for the rest.

At the time of this writing, it would be: Portrait only (for iPhones except 6 Plus/6s Plus) and Portrait AND Landscape for iPhone 6 Plus / 6s Plus, and iPad.

This is a similar behavior performed by the native Mail app.

I've tried among other things, the following:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

    return [.Portrait, .LandscapeLeft, .LandscapeRight]

}

override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {

    return (traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .Regular)

}
```

However, shouldAutororate is obviously called before the interface rotates, so that happens before traitCollection gets updated.

So, the question is, how to achieve this? I'm trying to accomplish this in the cleanest way possible without referencing explicitly userInterfaceIdiom, screen size, etc.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I'm interested in this too!

Answer (score 2):

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations:UIInterfaceOrientationMask{

    return [.portrait, .landscapeLeft, .landscapeRight]

}

override var shouldAutorotate:Bool {

    return (traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular) || (traitCollection.displayScale > 2);

}
```

Comment: Nice solution! My first idea was "but `traitCollection` isn't updated yet...", but the `traitCollection` in portrait combined with the `displayScale` does give us the info we need!